# Add a Seq# to an existing table, where the Seq# resets when a key value of a column changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequence

I have a table that lists my company's item# repeatedly in multiple rows, the only difference on each row is in another column that contains a customer's item# that they use to order our item# with (so when they order their item# we send them our corresponding item#).

I need a unique Seq# for each row **but I need that Seq# to reset back to 1 when my companies Item# changes.**

Sample data below of what the table has, and what I need it to look like in the Seq# column across multiple rows.  If it helps I also have an Item Master table that only has my companies item# one time for each item if that helps for a Join or something.

What my data looks like:

```
MyCoIt#    CustsXRefItem#    Seq#
123        FREDSITEM         Null
123        ABC456            Null
123        WIDGET1           Null
375        JANESITEM         Null
375        XYZB99            Null
375        WIDGET503         Null
375        WADGET573         Null
456        HELPME            Null    
800        INEEDIT           Null
```

What I need my data to look like:

```
MyCoIt#    CustsXRefItem#    Seq#
123        FREDSITEM         001
123        ABC456            002
123        WIDGET1           003
375        JANESITEM         001     <--Note Seq# reset when MyCoIt# changed
375        XYZB99            002
375        WIDGET503         003
375        WADGET573         004
456        HELPME            001     <--Note Seq# reset when MyCoIt# changed
800        INEEDIT           001     <--Note Seq# reset when MyCoIt# changed
```

I've tried code like this but can't figure out how to reset the counter when the value of MyCoIt# changes ...

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
UPDATE [stg].[ct_ItemAlias_counter]
SET [seqn] = @counter, @counter = @counter + 1
```

... but I don't know how to reset the @counter when the value of MyCoIt# changes.

Comment: Please don't use quirky update (lots of conversation about this [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)). Also, is this a one-time update? Why do you need leading 0s? What happens when someone deletes `XYZB99`?

Comment: It is a one-time update, and I don't need the leading zeroes.

Comment: @ScottMc did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `row_number` and an updatable CTE. You need to define the order the sequence number should be allocated within the `MyCoIt#` partition though - your data doesn't suggest any order.

```
with cte as (
    select id
        , row_number() over (partition by [MyCoIt#] order by [YouChoose]) rn
    from [stg].[ct_ItemAlias_counter]
)
update cte set
    [Seq#] = rn;
```